# What headers are included from a TCP stream when using read()?

Tags: c++, c, linux, sockets, tcp

I understand that a TCP "packet" contains several headers (Ethernet, IP, TCP, ...). When calling `read()` on a `SOCK_STREAM` socket, what header information is included? Does the kernel strip off some of the headers before exposing the data the application-space?

Scenario: I want to read TCP packets on a socket in my application. To get a full packet, I need to know the length of the packet. To know that, I need to know how to interpret the data read by the `SOCK_STREAM` socket, and to do that I need to know if the data I read includes the TCP header or only the information after the header.

Comment: No header information is included. You just get the data.

Comment: Yeah - at application level, with a TCP SOCK_STREAM socket, there are no packets.  read/recv, if sucessful and the connection is not closed, returns some number of streamed bytes above zero and not greater than the passed buffer size.  There is no guaranteed 1-1 correspondence with any packets or segments sent or received on any interfaces by any routes below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `read()`, you just get the data, none of the header information.

You can get information about the socket by using functions like `getsockaddr()` and `ioctl()`. But this won't return information about individual packets.

If you need packet-level details, you need to use something like `libpcap`.

Comment: I see, that makes sense. So when I see a packet in, for example, wireshark, everything after the TCP header is the data?

Comment: Yes, that's the data that you get with `read()`. Remember also that since it's a stream you don't even see packet boundaries -- a single call can return part of a packet or multiple packets.

Answer (score 0):

Using `read()` will not provide you with the header information you needed, but will only get you the data